# What's the purpose of $δx$ here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, notation

Why is the $δx$ here necessary? I'm going through Knuth's Concrete Math, and in the section on finite calculus, it says that it's akin to the $\mathrm{d}x$ of continuous integrals, but wouldn't it just be equal to one, since we increment by one when we're summing? I'm referring to sums of the form $\sum f(x)\delta x$

Comment: "_dx of continuous integrals_" and "_we increment by one when we're summing?_" Would you give the context ?

Comment: Took a brief look at the book. If you read Knuth's section carefully you will notice that the notation $\delta x$ has the same purpose as $dx$ in $\int g(x)\,dx\,.$ In calculus and integration we never need to define what $dx$ is and Knuth does not have to define what $\delta x$ is.